# mysql if else doing nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `eventorder` WHERE `group1` ='$group' and `eventno`='$evno' and `gen`='$gen'";
$a = mysql_query($sql3);
$g = mysql_fetch_object($a);
if ($g) {
    mysql_query("update `eventorder` set `ch_no`=concat(`ch_no`, ', $ch') where `group1` ='$group' and `eventno`='$evno' and `gen`='$gen'");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `eventorder` (`group1`,`eventno`,`eventname`,` ch_no`) VALUES ('$group','$evno','$evname','$ch') ");
}
```

Trying to insert when nothing is in the database and update when available, but my other codes are executing except this portion of the code. What's wrong?

Comment: You could always change $g = mysql_fetch_object($a); To $g = mysql_num_rows($a); the if statement would stay the same and it should work as you would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this with `insert . . . on duplicate key update` anyway.  First, create a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_eventorder_group1_eventno_gen on eventorder(group1, eventno, gen)
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO `eventorder` (`group1`,`eventno`,`eventname`,` ch_no`)
    VALUES ('$group', '$evno', '$evname', '$ch')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         ch_no = CONCAT(ch_no, ', ', VALUES(ch_no));
```

I am not sure if the duplicate should include `gen`, because your insert is not inserting that value anyway.

Comment: but i dont wanted to update eventname and if i dont create the key is there any other way?

Comment: CONCAT(ch_no, ', ', VALUES(ch_no)); is it correct or CONCAT(`ch_no`, ', VALUES(ch_no));

Comment: @Pinaki . . . I don't see how unbalanced single quotes could be correct.  For enforcing uniqueness of records (which appears to be your intention), you should use the database.  The unique index (or constraint) is the correct way to do this.

Comment: sorry I didnt notice the quote didn't close, but again nothing happend @gordon-linoff